# Using comma in expression and assigning it to variable

Tags: c

Please explain this block of code:

```
void main()
{   
    int t,
        a = 5,
        b = 10,
        c = 15;  
    t = (++a && ++b, ++a), ++a || ++c;   // need explanation for this line
    printf("%d  %d  %d %d", t, a, b, c);
}
```

Comment: I misread the question; I don't think it's a dupe of what I thought it was a dupe of.

Comment: please explain this block of code

Comment: Note that there are sequence points enough (at the comma operators, and also at the `&&` and `||` operators) that the code is not the usual case of undefined behaviour (so it is not a duplicate of the usual 'what is the result of `++i + i++`' type of question).

Comment: The return type of `main()` should be `int`, not `void`.

Comment: +1 @JonathanLeffler, yup.  If I could rescind my close vote, I would.  Answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comma operator returns the result of its second operand, and the `||` operator will short circuit.  So what happens in this case is:

1. `++a` is evaluated, `a` is now `6`.
2. Since the result of (1) was non-zero, the right side of the `&&` is evaluated.  That means `++b`, so `b` becomes `11`.
3. (1) and (2) are the left side of a comma operator, so the result of the `&&` is discarded.  (it's `1`, if that matters to you).
4. The `++a` on the right side of the first `,` is evaluated.  `a` is now `7`.
5. the assignment to `t` takes place - `t` is now `7`, the result of the first comma operator.
6. All of that was the left side of another comma operator, so the result (`7`) is discarded.  Next `++a` is evaluated.  `a` is now `8`.
7. Since `a` is not 0, the `||` short circuits, and the `++c` isn't evaluated. `c` stays `15`.

Results: `t` is `7`, `a` is `8`, `b` is `11`, and `c` is `15`.  The `printf` statement outputs:

```
7  8  11 15
```

Overall, this code would be easier to understand if you just wrote:

```
++a;
++b;
t = ++a;
++a;
```

Which has precisely the same behaviour.

Comment: +1: the assignment before the second comma operator is the bit that catches people out (me included when I first looked at it).  It is precisely why such constructs should be avoided in real code; they are nasty, tricky things to read.  Sometimes, there might be grounds for something faintly similar with more complex terms, but...it would likely be hidden in a macro, and would probably be better as an inline function, and still would be unlikely to increment the same variable 3 times.

Comment: Me too!  If I hadn't run it to check my answer, I'd have gotten it wrong myself.  In retrospect, I should have known.  It's pretty idiomatic to use the comma operator along with assignments in a `for` loop, for example.

Answer (score 6):

Execution ->

```
  t = (++a && ++b, ++a), ++a || ++c;  // () Priority
      ^
  t = (++a && ++b, ++a), ++a || ++c;  // ++a -> a = 6
        ^
  t = ( 6 && ++b, ++a), ++a || ++c;   // ++b -> b = 11
               ^
  t = ( 6 && 11 , ++a), ++a || ++c;   // 6 && 11 -> 1
           ^          
  t = ( 1 , ++a), ++a || ++c;         // ++a -> a = 7
            ^          
  t = ( 1 , 7), ++a || ++c;          // (1,7) -> 7 ... Comma operator has less priority 
          ^          
  t = 7, ++a || ++c;                //  (t = 7), ++a || ++c; ...Assigned value to t... Comma operator has less priority 
    ^
  ++a || ++c;                       // ++a -> a = 8
   ^          
  8 || ++c;                        //  8 || ++c -> 1 ...as 1 || exp -> 1...Logical OR skip next part if 1st exp is true  
    ^
```

Finally ->

```
t = 7
a = 8
b = 11
c = 15
```

Comment: Cool breakdown!  One small tweak, though - the assignment happens before the right side of the second comma operator is evaluated.

Comment: @RaghuSrikanthReddy...Thanx for compliment.

Answer (score 0):

```
int t, a = 5, b = 10, c = 15;
```

In C (and C++) the comma operator evaluates it's first operand, discards it and evaluates it's second operand and returns it.

`++a && ++b`  is first evaluated, a is now 6, b is now 11.

`(++a && ++b, ++a)` now the second operand to the right of the comma (`++a`) is evaluated, a is now 7. Also at this point t is assigned to the value 7. ***This is because the assignment operator has a higher precedence than the comma operator***.

(++a && ++b, ++a), ++a`now the second operand to the right of`(++a && ++b, ++a)`is evaluated. The third`++a` gives a's value as 8.

The logical `||` operator evaluates it's first operand and if it is `true` it does not evaluate the second operand. The first operand `(++a && ++b, ++a), ++a` is non-zero (true) and therefore the ++c is not evaluated. c's value remains at 15.